# Declaring variable inside a class with templated class type given template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, using

I am trying to instantiate a template class contained in a class which is given as a template parameter. This might be easier to understand with an example :

```
struct A {
static constexpr int a = 42;

class B {
  int b;
};

template<typename X>
class C {
  X c;
};
};

template<typename U, typename T>
class D {
  int a = U::a;

  using B = typename U::B;
  B b;

  //using C = typename U::C;
  // C<T> c;
  A::C<T> e;
};


int main(void) {
  D<A, int> d;
  return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment the commented lines, the compiler gives me an error which says C is not a template. I tried other approaches to instantiate this variable, but it didn't work. I would like to have the equivalent of the e variable but using the U typename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note you didn't declare `C` as a template type, then `C<T> c` will cause the error because you can't use it as a template type.

What you want is [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) (a name for a family of types), the correct syntax is:

```
template <typename Z>
using C = typename U::template C<Z>;
```

then

```
C<T> c;  // same as U::template C<T>; Z is substituted with T
```

With `D<A, int> d;`, `U` = `A` and `T` = `int`, then `C<T>` inside `D` is same as `A::C<int>`.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/YIOAX7967)

Comment: I had already tried this and I had got this error :error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
   using C = typename U::C<Z>

Comment: @Dam What compiler? I tried a demo [here](http://rextester.com/YIOAX7967).

Comment: No, it's fine now. Thanks :)